# How to find progress of database reindexing on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, index

When running:

```
REINDEX DATABASE CONCURRENTLY mydb;
```

which could take several hours, or even days, depending on the size of the database, is there anyway to get a rough estimate of its progress?

I've seen some forum posts claiming you can query index creation status with a query like:

```
SELECT 
  now()::TIME(0), 
  a.query, 
  p.phase, 
  p.blocks_total, 
  p.blocks_done, 
  p.tuples_total, 
  p.tuples_done,
FROM pg_stat_progress_create_index p 
JOIN pg_stat_activity a ON p.pid = a.pid;
```

The *_done/*_total columns in combination with phase does provide a rough progress percent. However, this only lists the progress of the currently updating index. It doesn't tell you how many other indexes are pending update, much less how much work there is to do for each.

Edit: I've tried combining the views `pg_index`, which lists the `*_ccnew` temporary indexes used by the concurrent process, with `pg_stat_progress_create_index` like:

```
SELECT relname,
CASE WHEN blocks_total > 0 THEN (ci.blocks_done/ci.blocks_total::numeric*100)::int ELSE NULL END as blocks_percent,
i.*
FROM pg_class as pgc
inner join pg_index as i on i.indexrelid = pgc.oid
left outer join pg_stat_progress_create_index as ci on ci.index_relid = i.indexrelid
WHERE i.indisvalid = false;
```

but this shows strange results. For my database, it lists ~300 indexes in pg_index that are temporary, and waiting to be updated. However, the one index cross referenced by pg_stat_progress_create_index that updates never is marked valid. It gets to 100% of blocks processed, and then disappears from `pg_stat_progress_create_index` but its `indisvalid` stays false. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the columns in `pg_index`, it looks like Postgres uses `indisvalid = false` to denote all the indexes being rebuilt and the subset of those with `indisready = true` denotes the indexes that `pg_stat_progress_create_index` has processed.

Using that, I think I can calculate a total progress percent with a query like:

```
SELECT
    m.complete_steps,
    m.total_steps,
    m.step_percent,
    (m.complete_steps/m.total_steps::numeric*100)::int AS total_percent
FROM (
    SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN blocks_total > 0 THEN (ci.blocks_done/ci.blocks_total::numeric*100)::int ELSE NULL END) AS step_percent,
    COUNT(*) AS total_steps,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN i.indisready THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS complete_steps
    FROM pg_class AS pgc
    INNER JOIN pg_index AS i ON i.indexrelid = pgc.oid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_stat_progress_create_index AS ci ON ci.index_relid = i.indexrelid
    WHERE i.indisvalid = false
) AS m
```

Answer (score 2):

`REINDEX DATABASE` command has no visible progress reporting in terms of overall work. Here is [relevant code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_STABLE/src/backend/commands/indexcmds.c#L2759) in postgresql source tree. `REINDEX DATABASE` will iterate over tables list and call (literally) `reindex table` for each individual relation in separate transaction. There is no progress report on how many relations have already been processed and how big the remaining list is.

The statuses in `pg_stat_progress_create_index` are reported by the cyclically called `reindex_relation`. So, it is useful from the point of view of processing a single index, but does not have information about the total amount of work across the entire database.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres 12 or later has the system view `pg_stat_progress_create_index`.
[It reports ...](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-DYNAMIC-VIEWS-TABLE)

> One row for each backend running `CREATE INDEX` or `REINDEX`, showing current progress.

Find details in the chapter [*CREATE INDEX Progress Reporting*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING) of the manual.

This is potentially ***very*** expensive on a busy server!

```
REINDEX DATABASE CONCURRENTLY mydb;
```

The manual has a chapter [*CREATE INDEX Phases*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PHASES) describing states of the column `phase`. In particular, consider:

> `waiting for old snapshots`
>
> `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` or `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` is waiting for transactions that can potentially see the table to release their snapshots. This phase is skipped when not in concurrent mode. Columns `lockers_total`, `lockers_done` and `current_locker_pid` contain the progress information for this phase.

Long-running transactions can stall the progress. Consider running `REINDEX CONCURRENTLY` on selected indexes. And `REINDEX DATABASE` at off-hours when you can afford to lock tables exclusively.

If your server is not actually busy, check for long-running transactions with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

The ones with `state = 'idle in transaction'` are the prime troublemakers (typically hint at a programming error, where transactions are not committed or rolled back). Those would likely show up in `pg_stat_progress_create_index.current_locker_pid` of stalled indexes.
Related:

- [Estimate end time for a long update](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125084/estimate-end-time-for-a-long-update/125202#125202)